# How to make page redirect work on next button click in bootstrap tour

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-tour

When any user lands on the page, he should see the first step as written below and clicking on the next button, he should redirect on the next page where I wish to send the user but it's not.

Here when I tried to do multi-step i.e. on landing show user some data and on the next step I redirect the page then it works absolutely fine but for single step only, it is not working.

I am using the latest version of the bootstrap tour files i.e. downloaded from their official site yesterday.

See the code below:-

```
var tour = new Tour({
            steps: [
                /*  {
                    element: "#site-tour-1-1",
                    title: "1",
                },*/ 
                {
                    element: "#site-tour-1-1",
                    title: "Search any business by typing initials",
                    //path: "/index2.html",
                    multipage: true,
                    onNext: function() {
                        window.location = "/index2.html"
                    }
                }     
            ],
            debug: true,
            backdrop: true,
            redirect:false,
            storage: window.localStorage,
            template: " <div class='popover tour'><div class='arrow'></div><h3 class='popover-title'></h3><div class='popover-content'></div><div class='popover-navigation'><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button><button class='btn btn-default end-tour' data-role='end'>End tour</button></div></div>",

        });
        tour.init();
        tour.restart();
```

Comment: Can you verify that `onNext` function is called (just put `alert('running');` before `window.location...`)?

Comment: @LukaPeharda no, alert is working fine only if first step is uncommented.

Answer (score 0):

Like said in the documentation of bootstrap-tour, you can manage a multipage tour by adding a field 'path' to one of your step. (See here : http://bootstraptour.com/api/#multipage)

In your case, you should do that :

```
var tour = new Tour({
        steps: [
            {
                element: "#site-tour-1-1",
                title: "Search any business by typing initials",
            },
            {
                element: "#site-tour-1-2",
                title: "This is my second step";
                path: "/index2.html"
            }
        ],
        debug: true,
        backdrop: true,
        storage: window.localStorage,
        template: " <div class='popover tour'><div class='arrow'></div><h3 class='popover-title'></h3><div class='popover-content'></div><div class='popover-navigation'><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button><button class='btn btn-default end-tour' data-role='end'>End tour</button></div></div>",

    });
    tour.init();
    tour.restart();
```

Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: thanks for the response. I do not want to use the first step i.e https://prnt.sc/mhqanz. I only want the second step and on clicking of next button, the user should redirect to the required page.